# How can I use a different TCP protocol in HTML5?

Tags: html, http, tcp

We are doing some experiments in the lab and we have rewrite a TCP implementation. Now our problem is if there's some methods that can make HTML5 use our TCP stack to transmit videos.

Thanks.

Update:
Sorry about the description. I didn't know much about web technology, maybe my question shuold replace HTML5 by Browser.

Comment: Do you realize that HTML (more HTTP than HTML) and and TCP operate at two different levels of the protocol stack, right?

Comment: If you replace the system's existing TCP implementation with your own, all software that uses TCP should wind up using your implementation.

Comment: There is no generic HTML5 implementation, no generic TCP stack, and so on. You have to tell us what this question is about. Is this a user-space TCP stack implemented on Windows? Is this a Linux kernel driver? Is the HTML5 in a browser? If so, which?

Comment: Also, the preferred choice for streaming videos is UDP, not TCP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything that is described in HTML is executed by the browser. HTML is not a programming language, it's markup. Therefore HTML has no influence on the internals of a browser.
Either you manage to get your browser to use a different TCP stack (which is unlikely unless you're working with Firefox or Chrome (or some other open source browser) and compile it from source), or you have to write your own browser.

Comment: Neither Firefox nor Chrome have a TCP stack in their codebase! It's an OS internal, mostly implemented in the Linux/Windows/Whatever kernel...

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo: Sure, but you could change those OS API calls into ones that use your stack. I guess (but it's just a guess), this is easier to accomplish than swapping the OS' TCP stack

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo:How about browser plugins?